# Extract data fom Marklogic 8.0.6 to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm using Marklogic 8.0.6 and we also have JSON documents in it. I need to extract a lot of data from Marklogic and store them in AWS S3. We tried to run "mlcp" locally and them upload the data to AWS S3 but it's very slow because it's generating a lot of files.

Our Marklogic platform is already connected to S3 to perform backup. Is there a way to extract a specific database in aws s3 ?

It can be OK for me if I have one big file with one JSON document per line

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about getting it to s3, but you can use [CORB2](https://github.com/marklogic/corb2) to extract MarkLogic documents to one big file with one JSON document per line.

Answer (score 1):

S3:// is a native file type in MarkLogic. So you can also iterate through all your docs and export them with xdmp:save("s3://...).

If you want to make agrigates, then You may want to marry this idea into Sam's suggestion of CORB2 to control the process and assist in grouping your whole database into multiple manageable aggregate documents. Then use a post-back task to run xdmp-save

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers. I do not know about CORB2, this is a great solution! But unfortunately, due to bad I/O I prefer a solution to write directly on s3.

I can use a basic Ml query and dump to s3:// with native connector but I always face memory error even launching with the "spawn" function to generate a background process.

Do you have any xquey example to extract each document on s3 one by one without memory permission?

Thanks

Comment: Can you integrate this text into your original question above? Otherwise it will be hard to distinguish answers from questions..